# Selection sort algorithm is failing for some cases

Tags: java, selection-sort

I am trying to implement selection sort algorithm. But i see that it is failing for some cases. I take two different arrays and get two different result.
Case 1: Integer [] arr= {100,90,6,43,12,1};   Result:{1,6,12,43,90,100}

Case 2: Integer [] arr= {100,90,6,43,12,7}; Result:{7,6,12,43,90,100}

Below is my code.

```
public class SelectionSort  {
    
    private static boolean less(Comparable v, Comparable w) {
        return v.compareTo(w)<0;
    }
    
    private static void exch(Comparable[] a,int i,int j) {
        Comparable swap=a[i];
        a[i]=a[j];
        a[j]=swap;
    }

    public static void sort(Comparable[] a) {

        int N= a.length;
        for(int i=0;i<N;i++) {
            int min=i;
            for(int j=i+1;j<N;j++) {
                if(less(a[j],a[min])) 
                    min=j;
                exch(a,i,min);

            }

        }
        
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change the algorithm like the following, it works fine

```
int N= a.length;
for(int i=0;i<N-1;i++) {
     int min=i;

     for(int j=i+1;j<N;j++) 
         if(less(a[j],a[min])) 
           min=j;
            
     exch(a,i,min);            
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you want the `exch` to happen inside the `j` loop?

Comment: hey, thanks for pointing this out. I kept it outside the loop and it then worked fine.